# Why is a logged-in user asked for a CAPTCHA?

Tags: support

A person who is logged-in on an account should not be told that they can not be distinguished from a 'machine', and required to fill out a CAPTCHA...   I'd really like to see a machine that and log-in and build up a rep at multiple SE sites and prepare an answer for yet another question...

Can someone tell me why a CAPTCHA would be required in such a circumstance and what possible answer a machine could come up with that would answer the question?

I was asked for a captcha before I was allowed to submit an answer to this question:

[Rounding a number up to the nearest multiple of a power of 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147315/rounding-a-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-a-power-of-2)

Comment: [This FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear) may be helpful.

Comment: Says a logged in user w/200 rep only has to answer a captcha every 5 minutes (at most).  Doesn't seem to say anything about why a logged in user should be captcha'd at all.  Says something about the intent of captchas being to prevent "flooding".  But does that really make sense?  How many logged in users are trying to flood, since there account would be quickly restricted if they became abusive?